# C# Декорирование класса Stream

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, декоратор

Задача заключается в следующем: необходимо задекорировать класс Stream таким образом, чтобы он дублировал все прочитанные байты список. Например, при чтении файла, каждый байт записывался в созданный список.
Вот код, который я написал:

```
public class DoubleToList : Stream
    {
        private readonly Stream _stream;
        private List<byte> _bytes;
        public Double(Stream stream, List<byte> bytes)
        {
            _stream = stream;
            _bytes = bytes;
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
                for(int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
                {
                    _bytes.Add(buffer[i]);
                }
            return buffer.Length;
        }
    }
```

Однако, когда просматриваю список байтов, то в нём записаны одни только нули. Непонятно как конкретно записывать считываемые данные в лист.

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, вам нужно исправить название конструктора.

А во-вторых, раз у вас декоратор, то нужно вызывать метод декорируемого класса (и не забывать про `offset` и `count`):

```
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    var readedBytesCount = _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    _bytes.AddRagne(buffer.Skip(offset).Take(readedBytesCount));

    return readedBytesCount;
}
```

Ну, и в-третьих, вы уже задавили этот вопрос ранее. Нужно было отредактировать его, а не создавать новый.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        _bytes.Add(buffer[i]);
    }
    return buffer.Length;
}
```

Comment: это явно неправильный ответ, вы игнорируете существование offset и count